# SELECT multiple tables with the same given id?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select multiple tables and want to display them as if they belong together.
I have 3 tables; users, profile and comment.
The table users has the following rows; id, name, password.
profile; id, userid, bio, website.
comments; id, userid, comment, date.

The id of the users table is the same as the userid from profile and comments. I want to show all of the results, but ordered, so the comment and profile information from that user, are shown with that user, example;

```
Username: Mister Noname
Bio: 25 years old
Website: http://google.com
Comments: Bla bla bla!!

Username: Jay Wit
Bio: 99 years old
Website: http://stackoverflow.com
Comments: Best website ever!
```

I tried using JOIN, but can't seem to get it to work right, can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you try to use `JOIN`? What didn't work? Did you get an error message or just not what you wanted?

Comment: Can you provide your statement? SQL is the way to go here.

Comment: I don't have the exact code anymore, but it was something line; `SELECT * FROM users NATURAL JOIN profile AND comments;` or `SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN comments AND profile WHERE comments.userid = users.id AND profile.userid = users.id;`, not sure but something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
select *
from users
inner join profile on profile.userid = users.id
inner join comments on comments.userid = users.id
where users.id = $id
order by users.id
```

This will give you all the informations you need for each row (= user). If you need some help to access theses data from PHP, I can help too, just let me know.

The ordering is down by user id, but anything is possible, just ask.

Hope this helps.

### Showing the data

Have a look at [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), this part particularly :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

`$result` is the result returned by `mysql_query`.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda understand that, but how can I display it? if $row was mysql_fetch_array, $row['users.name'] ?

Comment: I edited my answer, if you use mysql_fetch_array, indexes are numerical, you can access by column name with mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Thanks works like a charm! But what would happen if I had a table with a row called name and a page with a row called name and I would inner join them? Would $row['name'] display them both?

Comment: only the first one, the second one will be renamed by mysql, but the way it does this depends on the version. You can however give aliases to column name http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT u.name,p.bio,p.website,c.comment
FROM users u
JOIN profile p ON p.userid=u.id
JOIN comment c ON c.userid=u.id
ORDER BY u.id
```